# Proportional Editing circle missing

Tags: proportional-editing

I am trying to learn some basic automation.  I have drafting experience with AutoCAD and a friend recommended Blender.  There is a popular tutorial on the WEB with a guy who makes a doughnut and cup of coffee.  I was in the middle of doing that.  He explained the "proportional editing function.  I decided to reinforce my knowledge by repeating the first 8 or so steps without the video playing.  BUT when I got to the part where the proportional editing was required, I could no longer access the proportional editing  circle.  I have now repeated the tutorial 8 times (because I am insane and expected different results) and the circle will not come back.  I have searched the dozen or so Web entries, tried all the suggestions, and still there is nothing.

I really like the software, but if it is glitchy right off the bat, maybe not for me as a novice.  Is there something I am missing,  holding down the "G" and scrolling the mouse does absolutely nothing.

Comment: G is the _Move tool_. You can turn proportional editing with O (letter). You can also enable it by clicking the furthest right of the icons at the top-center of the viewport (icon looks like  a target next to a rounded mountain). If you still cannot see the circle with proportional edit enabled, it may be too large for the screen. scroll the mouse wheel forwards until you can see it (no need to hold anything)

Comment: Remember to scroll up (as if you were zooming in). Unless the circle is very, very small (which you can recognize by the fact nothing moves together with the selected objects) - then you need to scroll down to increase the influence circle.

Comment: I have done all of that.  2 days 4 hour sessions just trying to get that circle to come back. Read a comment about changing the proportional scale. Did that and for a moment it worked,  restarted the project because of the messed up shape,  When I cam back, nothing again. tried what just worked, and it didn't.  I am  frustrated and think this isn't for me.

Comment: I did take a quick video.  I am not sure if a youtube link is allowed.  unlikely. https://youtu.be/KjmjqlOPd6A

Comment: Don't hold down the g key.  type it once and let go of it.

Comment: good morning. I did both. I  holding down the "G" was a suggestion I saw somewhere else.  In the video I do not hold the G and get the same response.

Comment: Seems to have "discovered" my flaw. I was enabling using the on screen button. I instead used "O" to enable the Proportional editing, and it seems to work. I restarted he project and again used the onscreen button, nothing,  Then enebled it with "O" and back.   This seems to have solved my issue and quite a few others around the inerents I hope.

Comment: If you did shrink the influence disk under the 0 radius, you need to grow it again the same amount to reach the 0 radius again. To clarify: If you scroll the wheel say 2 seconds after the radius was already 0, then you now need to grow this radius about the same amount of time before something happens and a circle becomes visible again. In Blender's exotic logic a radius can likely be negative and negative values must be incremented back  prior a valid circle is drawn.

Answer (score 3):

If you cannot see the circle after following the advice of others to check the size of it by using the mouse wheel, try this: **check your pivot point**

I often trip myself up with this very thing. Check your pivot point for your operation. Press period (.) and if it's something other than bounding box center, this is likely the problem. I came here looking for answers and realized I tripped myself up on this very thing and if I haven't used proportional editing in a while, I usually end up learning this lesson over again.

I do not believe there's any way to turn off that circle, so the issue is often that it isn't showing *where* you'd expect.